# Access files of SharePoint Online Office 365

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I have an Office 365 account and I want to access the files of sharepoint.

Office 365 has REST APIs to access its services. I'm developing an application that is already consuming some apis like Calender, Contacts, Email and Files (One Drive for Business).

I want to consume Sharepoint, but I found nothing about it.

Is there a way to access Office365 Sharepoint files?

Thank you!

Comment: What kind of data do you want to access? Please provide some clarity.

Comment: Office 365 > Sites > {sitename} > list of files here. Look at this >>> http://s7.postimg.org/5oi7x4423/files_sharepoint.png . I want to access those files

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Microsoft's Graph API.
You can see an example of using it in a project I wrote
https://github.com/maximrub/SharePointOnlineTasker